# Creacion de columnas en Hightchart

Tags: php, javascript, array, highcharts

Buen dia, el ejemplo que debo mostrar es como el siguiente
http://tutlane.com/example/highcharts/highcharts-basic-bar-chart-example

aca es donde se recolectan los datos

```
var chartseries = [{
                name: 'Year 1800',
                data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 1900',
                data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 2012',
                data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
            }]
```

Pero si se dan cuenta en la grafica, muestra para africa 3 valores 107,33 y 1052

Pero en el array que yo llevo

[image: Como se dan cuenta en la imagen muestra 3 periodos]
Como se dan cuenta, en la imagen muestro 3 periodos, pero no me los esta agrupando correctamente
Para enero debe mostrarme la azul
Para febrero la negra
Para Marzo la verde

Pero agrupados en la misma casilla de la fecha

El array en javascript ya lo recorro asi

```
var datosfinales=[];
    for (var  i  in datos)
    {       
     datosfinales.push({type: 'column',
                yAxis:0,
                name: datos[i].name,
                data: datos[i].data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: datos[i].name

                },
                stack:datos[i].name
                })

    }
```

El resultado como lo muestra en la imagen a continuacion

Muchas gracias